# Can I pin arbitrary sites to the taskbar in IE9?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-9

Or do sites need to explicitly support it first?

Comment: What do you mean by explicitly supporting it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to pin any site. Just drag the tab from IE9 down to the task bar to pin it there.

I just tried it with several sites including our intranet and support portal, all worked flawlessly.

Comment: Oh. That’s the only way to do it? How terribly non-obvious!

Comment: And me thinking all the time this was not possible. I just pinned superuser.com... I guess I should leave it there....

Answer (score 3):

Another way to do this is:

- Press ALT to bring up the traditional window menu
- Select the Tools menu
- there should be an option called "Add site to Start Menu".

This is similar to the Chrome tool to make a website a standalone app (through this method the back and forward buttons will turn the predominant color of the favicon).

Comment: Hmm, what “arrows”?

Comment: The navigation backward/forward arrows. Also, I forgot to note that once in the start menu, you can pin it to the taskbar.   

This should be a link to that in action:
http://cid-52d8cb3a44c5d94b.office.live.com/embedphoto.aspx/.Public/nav%5E_arrows.png
The arrows should be red instead of the default blue.